# Android Time span picker

Tags: android, time, datetimepicker

I am designing an app that requires the user to pick

1. a time (e.g. 3 PM)
2. an additional value, representing a time gap (in minutes) before and after the selected time.

For example if the user has selected  15 PM  and 15   the app will consider times 2:45 PM  to 3:15 PM.

The trivial solution of a time selector combined with a list box, produces a long list with too many possible options for the time gap.

Another attempt was implementing it as a slider over 24  vertical lines  where the width of the slider is proportional to the time gap.  This approach was too difficult to operate on a small screen.

What is the best way to implement such a component?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are building a scientific app, people tend to set time in 5-minute increments. Then the picker may look like this:

[image]